# Pinhole camera model - Finding rotation from optical axis

Tags: camera, computer-vision, camera-calibration

In the pinhole camera model, is it possible to determine the rotation required from the optical/principal axis (the axis which pierces the image plane) to intersect a given pixel coordinate (u,v)?

I have an image where I am detecting a marker in space, and have the intrinsic and extrinsic camera parameters available. I am using the extrinsic parameters to cast a 2d ray into a separately constructed map (which is overhead and 2d), however I would like the ray angle to change depending on if the detected marker is to the left or right inside of the image.

My first thought was to use arctan utilizing the focal length and the u coordinate (x-axis on image plane from center of image) to determine an angle, however I don't think the units of measurement cooperate: one should be in real world meters and the other is arbitrary pixels.